# ADB Consumes 100% CPU

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just installed the latest Android SDK and ADT plugin for Eclipse on 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 (Macbook 5.5). I was disappointed to find that the adb process immediately began consuming 100% of my CPU. Even if I kill it, it seems to get respawned and again consumes 100% CPU, even if I'm not actually doing any Android dev in Eclipse.

Frustratingly, [this issue was reported](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4318) to Google two years ago, and nothing's been done about it.

Does anyone know of any workarounds? I can't even kill adb, because as long as Eclipse is running, it just gets respawned...